# How exactly do django serializers and views work together? And how can I return additional data with my queryset to the frontend?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm working with a react front end and a django rest framework backend, and I'm having trouble understanding what happens in between the view and the serializer. I want to return additional metadata that is not part of the queryset to the front end.

Here is the flow of my application

My frontend calls an endpoint:

```
Server.get("api/books-filtered")
```

This goes to a path in the backend written with django rest framework:

```
path("books-filtered/", Books.BookList.as_view()),
```

and then to

```
class Books(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    lookup_field = 'id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'book_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return only queries pertaining to the patient"""
        return FilterOutSomeBookRelatedQuerySetHere()
```

whose serializer class is:

```
class BookSerializer():
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['Title','Author','Publisher']
```

I get this back on the front end:

```
console.log(Server.get("api/books-filtered"))
// prints [
//{Title:"book 1", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 1"},
//{Title:"book 2", Author:"author 2", Publisher:"publisher 2"},
//{Title:"book 3", Author:"author 3", Publisher:"publisher 3"}
//]
```

What happens between the view and the serializer that causes the data to be formatted like that by the time its sent back to the frontend?

How can I modify what gets printed by console.log(Server.get("api/books-filtered")) to include additional metadata?
Like

```
console.log(Server.get("api/books-filtered"))
// prints [
//{Title:"book 1", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 1"},
//{Title:"book 2", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 2"},
//{Title:"book 3", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 2"}, 
//[3 books, 2 separate publishers, 1 author]
//]
```

or like:

```
console.log(Server.get("api/books-filtered"))
// prints 
// [{Title:"book 1", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 1", metadata:[1,2,3]},
//{Title:"book 2", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 2", metadata:[4,5,6]},
//{Title:"book 3", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 2", metadata:[7,8,9]}
//]
```

Answer (score 1):

Explaining here how DRF works is a bit out of scope but answering your question on how to add metadata is not. This can actually be easily done by extending your serializer class like so:

```
class BookSerializer(SurveySerializer):
    
    metadata = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_metadata(self, model_instance):
        # Use model instance or do another query all together
        return [1, 2, 3]

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['title', 'author', 'publisher', 'metadata']
```

The above will result in:

```
[
    {Title:"book 1", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 1", metadata:[1,2,3]},
    {Title:"book 2", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 2", metadata:[1,2,3]},
    {Title:"book 3", Author:"author 1", Publisher:"publisher 2", metadata:[1,2,3]}
]
```

By using `SerializerMethodField` you can essentially populate the `metadata` field with whatever you want by implementing `get_metadata`.

Comment: Hi Thanks! I'm calculating my metadata in my view right now, is there anyway I can pass that data into my serializer and return it as metadata from there?

Comment: Yeah you can use the serializer context for that.